# Laravel - the same validator works in one controller method but doesn't work in another

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I have two simmilar forms, one for adding news to site, another to edit news:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MyController@verifyAdminAddNews', 'files' => true)) }}

        {{ Form::text('title', Form::old('title'), ['required' => 'required']) }}<br><br>
        {{ Form::textarea('subtitle', Form::old('subtitle'), ['required' => 'required', 'style' => 'height:60px;']) }} <br><br>
        {{ Form::textarea('text', Form::old('text'), ['required' => 'required']) }} <br><br>
        {{ Form::file('image', '') }}

        @if(isset($errormessage))
            <div class="error-message"> {{ $errormessage }} </div>
        @endif

        {{ Form::submit('Pridať novinku', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MyController@verifyAdminEditNews', 'class'=>'bg-grey width')) }}
        {{ Form::text('title',$item->title, ['required' => 'required']) }}<br><br>
        {{ Form::textarea('subtitle', $item->subtitle, ['required' => 'required', 'style' => 'height:60px;']) }} 
        {{ Form::textarea('text', $item->text, ['required' => 'required']) }} <br><br>
        {{ Form::file('image', '') }}

        @if(isset($errormessage))
            <div class="error-message"> {{ $errormessage }}</div>
        @endif

        {{ Form::submit('Upraviť novinku', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and in Controller are two methods for adding and editting news:

```
public function verifyAdminAddNews(){ 

    if (is_object(DB::table('news')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first())) {
        $newid = DB::table('news')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first()->id + 1; }
    else { $newid = 0; }

    // validate if file is image
    $input = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
    $rules = array('image' => 'image');
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Input::flash();
        return View::make('adminnadd', ['errormessage' => 'Chyba! Vybratý súbor nie je obrázok.'] );

    } else {  

        if (Input::file('image')==null) { 

            DB::insert('INSERT INTO news (id, title, subtitle, text, imageurl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
                    array($newid, Input::get('title'), Input::get('subtitle'), Input::get('text'), 'none'));

        } else {

            $destination = 'uploadedimages';
            $filename = 'image'.$newid;

            Input::file('image')->move($destination, $filename);

            DB::insert('INSERT INTO news (id, title, subtitle, text, imageurl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
                    array($newid, Input::get('title'), Input::get('subtitle'), Input::get('text'), $filename));

        }

        return View::make('adminnall',['items'=>DB::table('news')->get()]);
    }           
}

public function verifyAdminEditNews() {

    $id = Session::get('editnewsid');

    // validate if file is image
    $input = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
    $rules = array('image' => 'image');
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Input::flash();
        return View::make('adminnedit', ['errormessage' => 'Chyba! Vybratý súbor nie je obrázok.'] );

    } else {  

        if (Input::file('image')==null) { 
            DB::table('news')->where('id', $id)->update(array('title' => Input::get('title'), 'subtitle' => Input::get('subtitle'), 'text'=>Input::get('text')));

        } else {

            $destination = 'uploadedimages';
            $filename = 'image'.$id;

            Input::file('image')->move($destination, $filename);
            DB::table('news')->where('id', $id)->update(array('title' => Input::get('title'), 'subtitle' => Input::get('subtitle'), 'text'=>Input::get('text'), 'imageurl' => $filename ));
        }

        return View::make('adminnall',['items'=>DB::table('news')->get()]);
    }   
}
```

These methods have exactly the same Validator for validating if selected file is image. In verifyAdminAddNews it works right, returning error message back to view with form, when file is not image. But in verifyAdminEditNews validator will NOT fails when file is not image and will not return error message. How is this possible?

Comment: You can do a return Input::file('image'); to check if the same file it's in both controllers, but sounds quite strange. The two forms are different right? Because they look almost the same, perhaps you can improve that afterwards, and create only one changing only the things you need on each case.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I forgot to add 'files' => 'true' to second form.